# Configure two IP's for Virtual boxx

Tags: virtualbox

I have created a RHEL guest on my virtual box running on windows 7. I need to configure a external IP from which I can access the Guest RHEL machine, and RHEL guest machine should have a internal IP. Something like public and private IP. is this possible?

Comment: Did the answer below helped you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is already answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/363003/no-internet-connection-on-virtualbox-windows-7-as-guest-ubuntu-13-04-as-host

> - Open Virtualbox Manager
> - Select the machine you cannot get internet on in the left pane
> - Click the Settings button in the top menu
> - Click Network in the left pane in the settings window
> - Switched to Bridged Adapter in the Attached to drop-down menu
> - Select the name of the network adapter you are currently using on your host machine. I am using wireless so I chose eth0 which is my
>     wireless network adapter. You can check which adapter you are
>     currently using by opening the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T by default) and
>     running ifconfig. It will probably be the eth adapter that shows an
>     inet addr and shows data transfer next to RX bytes.
> - Under Advanced, make sure the machine is using the Desktop Adapter Type
> - Under Advanced, make sure Promiscuous Mode is set to Allow VMs
> - Under Advanced, make sure Cable connected is checked on
> - Hit OK to save your changes
> - Start your VM